# How do I mass delete events on google calendar based on keyword?

Tags: calendar, gcal

So I am at school, and I synced my school's schedule-software to my google calendar, which creates an individual event for every lesson.

Since there is a problem with the software our school uses, they put every lesson in there 3 times (all with different times too), which is really annoying.

And since the wrong ones all share the same keyword, I would love a script which I can run to remove all of these wrong events.

I already found this script, but this one deletes everything between certain dates, but I need one that removes them by keyword. Since I am a beginner to coding, I would need some help of some of you.

Here is the code I already found: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/47768

Comment: Hi @tellamana, could you show us at least a bit of code you've tried so far? This is not a code development service, so you should first try something and when you have a problem you can't solve ask here for help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool to do this and more. Take a look at the source at https://github.com/thomasmhofmann/google-calendar-tools.